# How does the combination of `\huge` and `\bm` work?

Tags: symbols

I've recently come  up with some strange behaviors of simultaneous applications of `\huge` and `\bm`. In particular, the results are not consistent depending on the loaded packages.

**MWE 1**: (with the minimum loaded packages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
  $\Delta \qquad \bm{\Delta} \qquad {\Huge\bm{\Delta}}$

  $q \qquad \bm{q} \qquad {\Huge\bm{q}} $ 
\end{document}
```

**Result 1**:

[image]

In this case, `\bm` works, but `\huge` has no influence.

**MWE 2**: (with the loaded packages corresponding to a specific project of mine)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for times font
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} % for subnumbering in cases
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, bottom = 1.5cm, top = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew,utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  $\Delta \qquad \bm{\Delta} \qquad {\Huge\bm{\Delta}}$

  $q \qquad \bm{q} \qquad {\Huge\bm{q}} $ 
\end{document}
```

**Result 2**:

[image]

This one seems even more strange, and the results are somewhat unexpected!

Are these behaviors justifiable?

**Edit**:

I have a matrix equation, and there is an `\underbrace` for each matrix. The names of the matrices, e.g., `\Delta` and `q`, are about to be put there. But the labels are so small, and I need to make them bigger. What is the best practice to do this?

- `scalebox`,
- `mathlarger`,
- ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for times font
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} % for subnumbering in cases
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm, bottom = 1.5cm, top = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew,utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:vec1}
  \nabla \xi(\bm{q}) = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \nabla \xi(q^{0}) \\ \nabla \xi(q^{1}) \\ \nabla \xi(q^{2}) \\ \nabla \xi(q^{3}) \\   \nabla \xi(q^{4}) \\ \nabla \xi(q^{5}) \\ \nabla \xi(q^{6}) 
  \end{bmatrix} = 
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{3} &0&0&0&0\\
    2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3} &0&0&0&0\\
    2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1} &0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}&0&0\\
    0&0&0&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1}&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}\\
    0&0&0&0&0&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1} 
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\huge\bm{\Lambda}}
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    q^{0}\\q^{1}\\q^{2}\\q^{3}\\q^{4}\\q^{5}\\q^{6}
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\huge\bm{q}}
  +2\omega\lambda_{2}
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{0},q^{1}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{0},q^{2})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{1},q^{0}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{1},q^{2})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{2},q^{0}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{2},q^{1})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{3},q^{4})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{4},q^{3})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{5},q^{6})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{6},q^{5})
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\huge\bm{\Omega}}       
  +
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{3}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{4}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{4}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{3}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{5}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{6}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{6}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{5}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\huge\bm{C}} 
  = 0,
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Command \Huge invalid in math mode`

Comment: @egreg: I see. Then, what is the best practice to change the size of stuffs in math mode? `scalebox`?

Comment: There is `\mathlarger` from the `relsize` package, if you *really* need to do it. What precisely is your aim?

Comment: @egreg: I have a matrix equation, and there is an `\underbrace` for each matrix. The names of the matrices, e.g., `\Delta` and `q` are about to be put there. But the labels are so small, and I need to make them bigger.

Comment: `{\underbrace{whatever}_{\textstyle\bm{\Delta}}}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. However, this solution doesn't seem to be much flexible, say, what if one needs to make the symbol even bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a warning `Command \Huge invalid in math mode` and the result is thus unpredictable.

Use `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for times font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:vec1}
\begin{split}
\nabla \xi(\bm{q}) &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \nabla \xi(q^{0}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{1}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{2}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{3}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{4}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{5}) \\
    \nabla \xi(q^{6}) 
  \end{bmatrix} = 
  {\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{3} &0&0&0&0\\
    2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3} &0&0&0&0\\
    2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1} &0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}&0&0\\
    0&0&0&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1}&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&2\lambda_{1}&2\lambda_{3}\\
    0&0&0&0&0&2\lambda_{3}&2\lambda_{1} 
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\bm{\Lambda}}}
  {\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    q^{0}\\q^{1}\\q^{2}\\q^{3}\\q^{4}\\q^{5}\\q^{6}
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\bm{q}}}
  \\[2ex]
  &\quad+2\omega\lambda_{2}
  {\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{0},q^{1}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{0},q^{2})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{1},q^{0}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{1},q^{2})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{2},q^{0}) + \mathcal{Q}(q^{2},q^{1})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{3},q^{4})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{4},q^{3})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{5},q^{6})\\
    \mathcal{Q}(q^{6},q^{5})
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\bm{\Omega}}}
  +
  {\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{2}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}(q^{0}_{\mathcal{T}} + q^{1}_{\mathcal{T}})\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{3}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{4}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{4}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{3}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{5}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{6}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)\\
    2\bigl(\lambda_{1}q^{6}_{\mathcal{T}} + \lambda_{3}q^{5}_{\mathcal{T}}\bigr)
    \end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\bm{C}}} 
  \\
  &= 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could use `\textstyle\mathlarger{\bm{\Lambda}}`, but I don't see a real reason for it (requires `\usepackage{relsize}`).